# Scrape values from website using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Help needed in order to scrape some data from a website.
As a first step i manage to visit the website and import my variables but:

1.i don't know how to press "Convert currencies" button
2.and afterwards to get "Converted Amount" & "Rate" to excel.

any help will be appreciate!!!

```
Sub Test()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Dim Amount As String
Dim Source As String
Dim Target As String
Dim Datestring As String

Amount = 10000
Source = "Euro"
Target = "UK pound sterling"
Datestring = "03-08-2018"

'Open Browser and download data
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/curConverter.do?sourceAmount=" & _
            Amount & _
            "&sourceCurrency=" & _
            Source & _
            "&targetCurrency=" & _
            Target & _
            "&inputDate=" & _
            Datestring & _
            "&submitConvert.x=209&submitConvert.y=10"

            submitConvert.Click

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: @QHarr any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [XmlHttpRequest (XHR):](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)

Faster to use XHR where there is no browser opening.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetRates()
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object
    Dim sourceAmount As String, sourceCurrency As String, targetCurrency As String, inputDate As String
    sourceAmount = "10000"
    sourceCurrency = "EUR"
    targetCurrency = "GBP"
    inputDate = "03-08-2018"
    Dim url As String
    url = "http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu//curConverter.do?sourceAmount=" & sourceAmount & "&sourceCurrency=" & sourceCurrency & _
        "&targetCurrency=" & targetCurrency & "&inputDate=" & inputDate & "&submitConvert.x=52&submitConvert.y=8"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    With html
       .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
        clipboard.SetText .querySelectorAll("table.tableopenpage").item(1).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Less robust but if you just want the

**converted amount:**

```
.querySelectorAll("table.tableopenpage").item(1).getElementsbytagname("td")(7).innertext
```

And the **rate**:

```
.querySelectorAll("table.tableopenpage").item(1).getElementsbytagname("td")(10).innertext
```

---

**Output:**

[image: output]

---

**References:**

```
Microsoft Forms Object Library (or add a userform to your project)
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

---

### Internet Explorer:

The data is already there due to the query string you are using in the URL. No need for a click.

Just use the correct abbreviations for currencies.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, Amount As String, Source As String, Target As String
    Dim Datestring As String, hTable As HTMLTable

    Amount = 10000
    Source = "EUR"
    Target = "GBP"
    Datestring = "03-08-2018"
    Dim url As String
    url = "http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/curConverter.do?sourceAmount=" & _
          Amount & _
          "&sourceCurrency=" & _
          Source & _
          "&targetCurrency=" & _
          Target & _
          "&inputDate=" & _
          Datestring & _
          "&submitConvert.x=209&submitConvert.y=10"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Dim clipboard As Object
        Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
        clipboard.SetText .document.getElementsByClassName("tableopenpage")(1).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**If interested in how to click though:**

1) Use the correct 3 letter abbreviations for the currencies.

2) You can click the submit button with:

```
.document.querySelector("input[name=submitConvert]").Click
```

It uses a CSS selector of

```
input[name=submitConvert]
```

This says

element with `input` tag having an attribute `name` whose value is `submitconvert`.

3) You then need a

```
While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

to allow the page to refresh.

4) You can then grab the results table with:

```
.document.querySelectorAll("table.tableopenpage").item(1)
```

This collects all elements with a tag `table` and class `tableopenpage`. You want the second of these, which is 1 on a 0-based index system.

---

**References required:**

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft Forms Object Library
```

---

**Other:**

I find it simpler to grab the table in one go but you could target the rate, for example, more specifically with a CSS selector of:

```
a[target*=quickview]
```

Be aware that Excel may swop Date from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy on output and so you will need to correct this, or at least be aware of it.

Comment: thanks a lot for for your fast replay.is there any way instead of pasting all this data to get only this two values:
1. 8905.00 GBP 
2. 1 EUR = 0.8905 GBP

Comment: i try to use your updates for the Internet Explorer method and i receive an error with the interface.

Comment: Why not use the other method? And what is the exact error message for Internet Explorer? And is it resolved by using Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium?

Comment: i manage to find a solution!@QHarr you save my back anaother time!thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I scrape the values and use them as caption on a currency converter userform :
frmCurrencyConverter.lblConverted.Caption = .document.getElementsByClassName("tableopenpage").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(7).innerText

rmCurrencyConverter.lblRateRate.Caption = .document.getElementsByClassName("tableopenpage").Item(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(10).innerText